# Counter example for AGM inequality proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[AGM inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0llRI.jpg)

AGM equality is easy and clear proposition.
I know how to prove this proposition.
However, why does we need the condition that equality holds in each only when x=y?
What will be counter-example for AGM when x is not equal to y.

Comment: For $x=0$ and $y=2$, see that all $\leq$'s are actually $<$'s.

Comment: However, in that case, can we just use = sign for all of inequality instead of <= when x=y

Comment: The equality holding only when $x=y$ means that $\color{grey}{\underbrace{\color{black}{2xy=x^2+y^2}}_{\mathop{\iff}{(x-y)^2=0}}}\implies x=y$.

Comment: Oh, that makes everything clear. Thanks Gud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding "condition" in this case. The word usually means an extra assumption or hypothesis. The "equality holds only when ..." is not necessarily part of the statement of the AGM. The AGM is true, with "less than or equal to", (as you know) for every $x$ and $y$. The extra thing you're calling a condition strengthens the AGM by describing the only situation in which you have equality. It's not something you "need" to prove the AGM.

Edit:

I seem to have used lots of words to say something that @GitGud 's comment explained to your satisfaction.

Comment: Thanks Bolker.
This is my first time to study math in English. I was confused 'term'(meaning of word) Thanks for explanation.